How to log in a user from your spring boot api in keycloak?
im an intern working on a project where we have a frontend using react and a backend using spring boot and we are trying to use keycloak
from every doc i have read  i saw that the frontend should use keycloak form to login the user and then if its succefull we will only use the jwt to get the resources in our backend api
but my manager keeps insisting on using the backend api to communicate with keycloak and leave the frontend to only communicate with the api
he keeps mentionning authorization code
i honestly have no idea what to do i tried to find a tutorial but i can find anything
i tried to use admin-cli to login the user from an endpoint using his username and password but it didnt work for me either
what should i do ?
if anyone can give a detail process of how to do this i would appreciate it


frontend should use keycloak form to login the user and then if its succefull we will only use the jwt to get the resources in our backend api

You have not fresh enough (or educated enough) sources. According to recent recommendations (not that recent, though), tokens should be delivered only to confidential clients. As neither single-page nor mobile applications can keep a secret, this means that OAuth2 clients should stand on servers you trust. It is also recommended that tokens do not leave the server:

this is safer (tokens cannot be stolen on the network, by compromised Javascript dependencies, from device storage, etc.)
this allows keeping control over user session: a JWT is immutable and can't be revoked. If you send it over the network all you can do is wait for it to expire, access to resource servers remaining allowed until then. But if tokens remain on your server, you can delete them when invalidating a user session, immediately revoking user access

The currently recommended way to authorize single-page and mobile applications with OAuth2 is to use a the Backend for Frontend (BFF) pattern: a Middleware in charge of:

keeping sessions for the frontend (with protection against CSRF)
driving authorization code and refresh token flows
storing tokens (usually in session)
replacing session cookie with the access token in session when forwarding a request from the frontend to a resource server

As you're using React, maybe you're app is using Next.js, in which case you could use the NextAuth lib which follows this pattern: the OAuth2 client is confidential, running in the server-side part of the app (node). Tokens are not sent to the browser.
But I have a preference for spring-cloud-gateway to implement BFFs:

works whatever is used for the frontend
relatively easy to configure thanks to the TokenRelay filter and spring-boot-stater-client
easy to scale (integrates well with Spring Session and can be easily compiled to a native image)
easy to observe (as any Spring Boot 3 app, implementing advanced observability is a piece of cake)

I wrote an article for Baeldung on this subject.
